# How to Automate new Facebook Sign up popup?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, automation

I've tried to Automate Facebook Signup page (new version consists of a popup). I've tried to switch to `iframe` but I've failed to find it.

Please help me. Please share the code.

Comment: Why would you need to automate signing up to Facebook? I can’t imagine any _non_-spammy context, in which one would ever need that.

Comment: Firstly, you should share some code and then we would go from there, Secondly, Like CBrone said there is no way this is not spamming related.

Comment: @CBroe I tried just for practice Automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below worked for me. Signup section is not any new pop-up window or frame. So don't need to switch to any frame or window. Just locate the fields and enter the required data using methods like sendKeys, clicks etc.

```
    WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    Driver.get(url);
    WebElement createAcount=Driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_2"));
    createAcount.click();
    WebElement firstname=Driver.findElement(By.id("u_1_b"));
    firstname.sendKeys("Tina");
    WebElement surname=Driver.findElement(By.id("u_1_d"));
    surname.sendKeys("Roy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Sign-up input fields are NOT in the `iframe`, so you don't need to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing this test. The elements are dynamically generated so they have different values everytime. Group the element selection by more attributes